# Kernel Density Estimation

Tags: kernel-smoothing

In the Kernel density estimation formula below (from [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kernel_density_estimation)), what do the values of $x$ and $x_i$ represent?

$$
\hat f_h(x) = \frac{1}{n}\sum_{i=1}^n K_h(x-x_i) = \frac{1}{nh}\sum_{i=1}^n K\bigg(\frac{x-x_i}{h}\bigg)
$$

I am implementing this formula but I am not sure about what they really represent. I know what values use for $x_i$, but I don't know what I'm passing in for $x$.

Comment: Can you list the formula you are using?

Comment: $x_i$ is a data value and the function is being evaluated at $x$.

Comment: The formula is in this link: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kernel_density_estimation.  I know what to use for xi, but i don't know what passing in x

Comment: Typically, $x$ would be one of a grid of points on a range that at least covers that of your data set.

Comment: But if, for example, my xi are: 2, 4, 6, 8... etc what is my correspondinf x value?

Comment: You should be building a function, using the $x_i$'s, so that you can pass in any $x$ and get a value. So, you create your function using only the $x_i$'s and if (say) your boss says "evaluate the function at $x=\pi$" you should be able to pass it to your function and get a value.

Comment: Catia, Have run across [this video](https://youtu.be/QSNN0no4dSI)?

Comment: This tutorial explains it in details for noobie level [enter link description here](http://www.homeworkhelponline.net/blog/math/tutorial-kde)

Answer (score 3):

Since this doesn't have an answer yet, I'll expand my comment a little:

$x$ is the argument you're evaluating (calculating) the function (the density estimate) at.

$x_i$ the value of the $i$-th data point.

To draw the density, you'd normally evaluate $x$ across some reasonably fine grid of values.

> But if, for example, my $x_i$ are: 2, 4, 6, 8... etc what is my corresponding x value?

$x$ will be whatever value you want to know $\hat{f}(x)$ at. This is like any other function -- If I said "here's a parabola, $g(x) = 3x^2-8x+5$" you're basically asking "but what value is $x$?". The answer is whatever value(s) you want to know $g$ at.